# Adding Motion Blur to a Plane

Tags: eevee-render-engine, motion-blur

I have a simple scene in which the camera is moving backwards away from the stage over the "crowd". The crowd is being represented by a plane with Voronoi Texture and Color Ramp nodes.
My problem is that when the camera moves backwards there is no motion blur on the crowd, please see the picture below of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

AND this is the result that I am getting:
[image]

Does anyone know how to make these lights stretch to simulate fast camera movement?

Comment: Well… That looks like it should be working. However, the second screenshot is just of the viewport. Motion blur may not be visible there. Fully render the scene, and see what happens. Have you tried moving the camera faster?

Comment: Hi, I have rendered a scene multiple times and have tried moving the camera faster. I have now replaced the Voronoi texture with a hair particle system for which I created spheres with emission and set particle system to render my spheres as a collection. It works slightly better but there is still no stretched trail of light as in the first picture I provided. I have also adjusted the motion blur settings - setting "shutter" to 0.15 and "steps" to 4 but the lights looks separate not as one line if that makes sense